# Change the classes of <table> nodes generated from Pandoc

Tags: css, haskell, pandoc, css-tables

I see there's a syntax for [adding different attributes](http://pandoc.org/demo/example9/pandocs-markdown.html) (under "Header Identifiers in HTML...") to various markdown constructs, like headers and blockquotes. Could the same be accomplished for tables?

I looked through [the extensions](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-1.15.0.6/docs/Text-Pandoc-Options.html#t:Extension) and [other options](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-1.15.0.6/docs/Text-Pandoc-Options.html#t:WriterOptions) for configuring Pandoc, but couldn't find something suitable to change how Pandoc adds classes to its nodes.

Comment: Blunderbuss suggestion: I often use [tagsoup](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagsoup) to post-process HTML output from Pandoc.

Comment: I don't think it's possible at this point. There's an ongoing discussion [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/684).